# Setting texinputs with .bat file (texlive2012)

Tags: windows, texinputs

How can I append additional paths for LaTeX to search for external `.sty` and `.cls` files using `.bat` file.

My try:

```
set TEXINPUTS=D:\myfolder    latex %1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format that works here nicely is:

```
set TEXINPUTS=D:/myfolder//;
```

LaTeX then searches in this folder and its subfolders.